# Vega-lite: Legend label expression to include value of multiple fields

Tags: javascript, charts, vega-lite, vega

My code is as follows;

```
{
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "width": 800,
      "height": 200,
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "pre_120": 0,
            "pre_90": 0,
            "pre_60": 0,
            "post_60": 100,
            "post_90": 150,
            "post_120": 200,
            "type": "Mango",
            "count": "twenty"
          },
          {
            "pre_120": 0,
            "pre_90": 0,
            "pre_60": 0,
            "post_60": 90,
            "post_90": 140,
            "post_120": 190,
            "type": "Apple",
            "count": "ten"
          }
        ]
      },
      "transform": [
        {"fold": ["pre_120", "pre_90", "pre_60","0", "post_60", "post_90", "post_120"]}
      ],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "key",
              "sort": [
                "pre_120",
                "pre_90",
                "pre_60",
                "0",
                "post_60",
                "post_90",
                "post_120"
              ]
            },
            "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
          }
        },
  {
    "mark": { 
      "type": "rule", 
      "color": "maroon", 
      "size": 3 ,
      "strokeDash": [6, 4]},
    "encoding": {
      "x": { "datum": "0" }
    }
  }
  ]
  }
```

Below is the link to the vega editor.

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/947b2a99801bc6a08d468cdb9acbeb50/legend.json

My aim is to show the legend to include value of 2 fields i.e. **type and count fields** with a hyphen.
Example :
In the image below, I wanted to show the legends as
'Apple - twenty'
and
'Mango - ten'
How could I do the same?
[image]

Comment: Where are the values for ten and twenty coming from in your dataset?

Comment: I have just updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I would just create a new calculated field and use that.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "pre_120": 0,
        "pre_90": 0,
        "pre_60": 0,
        "post_60": 100,
        "post_90": 150,
        "post_120": 200,
        "type": "Mango",
        "count": "ten"
      },
      {
        "pre_120": 0,
        "pre_90": 0,
        "pre_60": 0,
        "post_60": 90,
        "post_90": 140,
        "post_120": 190,
        "type": "Apple",
        "count": "twenty"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["pre_120", "pre_90", "pre_60", "post_60", "post_90", "post_120"]},
     {"calculate": "datum.type + ' - ' + datum.count", "as": "label"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "key",
          "sort": [
            "pre_120",
            "pre_90",
            "pre_60",
            "post_60",
            "post_90",
            "post_120"
          ]
        },
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "field": "label",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As always, Thank you so much. It worked! Still counting the days when things will click and I will be able to handle these issues on my own. Till then, you will definately hear from me again with another issue that can be easily solved, just not by me. Thank you again!